# Template class [] not found In AdminServiceProvider.php line 92

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-6

I want to add to my project the package `"laravelrus/sleepingowl": "dev-development"` . I've added in compose.json `"laravelrus/sleepingowl": "dev-development"`.
I have ran `./compose.phar update` in terminal.

It looks like it is installing the packages correctly but it can't run any artisan command:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 21 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
// packages are installed with success 
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In AdminServiceProvider.php line 92:

  Template class [] not found  


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I have tried to remove the package and looks like after that `php artsan` work fine. If I add back the package, the error appear again. Because of this, I cannot run any `php artisan` command until I don't remove the package.

Can anyone help me with this?

The github url to the line that throw the exception: https://github.com/LaravelRUS/SleepingOwlAdmin/blob/master/src/Providers/AdminServiceProvider.php#L92

```php
namespace SleepingOwl\Admin\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\AliasBinder;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Contracts\Display\TableHeaderColumnInterface;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Contracts\Form\FormButtonsInterface;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Contracts\Repositories\RepositoryInterface;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Contracts\Widgets\WidgetsRegistryInterface;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Exceptions\TemplateException;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Model\ModelConfigurationManager;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Navigation;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Routing\ModelRouter;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Templates\Assets;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Templates\Meta;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Widgets\EnvEditor;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Widgets\Messages\ErrorMessages;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Widgets\Messages\InfoMessages;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Widgets\Messages\MessageStack;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Widgets\Messages\SuccessMessages;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Widgets\Messages\WarningMessages;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Widgets\WidgetsRegistry;
use SleepingOwl\Admin\Wysiwyg\Manager;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo;

class AdminServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $directory;

    /**
     * All global widgets.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $widgets = [
        EnvEditor::class,
    ];

    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerWysiwyg();
        $this->registerTemplate();
        $this->initializeNavigation();
        $this->registerAliases();

        $this->app->singleton('sleeping_owl.widgets', function () {
            return new WidgetsRegistry($this->app);
        });

        $this->app->booted(function () {
            $this->app['sleeping_owl.widgets']->placeWidgets(
                $this->app[ViewFactory::class]
            );
        });

        $this->app->booted(function () {
            $this->registerCustomRoutes();
            $this->registerDefaultRoutes();
            $this->registerSupportRoutes();
            $this->registerNavigationFile();

            $this->app['sleeping_owl']->initialize();
        });

        ModelConfigurationManager::setEventDispatcher($this->app['events']);
    }

    protected function registerTemplate()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('assets.packages', function ($app) {
            return new \KodiCMS\Assets\PackageManager();
        });

        $this->app->singleton('sleeping_owl.meta', function ($app) {
            return new Meta(
                new Assets(
                    $app['assets.packages']
                )
            );
        });

        $this->app->singleton('sleeping_owl.template', function (Application $app) {
            if (! class_exists($class = $this->getConfig('template'))) {
                throw new TemplateException("Template class [{$class}] not found");
            }

            return $app->make($class);
        });

        if (file_exists($assetsFile = __DIR__.'/../../resources/assets.php')) {
            include $assetsFile;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $key
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getConfig($key)
    {
        return $this->app['config']->get('sleeping_owl.'.$key);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getBootstrapPath($path = null)
    {
        if (! is_null($path)) {
            $path = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path;
        }

        return $this->getConfig('bootstrapDirectory').$path;
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerMessages();
        $this->registerBootstrap();
        $this->registerWidgets();
    }

    /**
     * Global register widgets.
     */
    protected function registerWidgets()
    {
        $widgetsRegistry = $this->app[WidgetsRegistryInterface::class];

        foreach ($this->widgets as $widget) {
            $widgetsRegistry->registerWidget($widget);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Global register messages of adminpanel.
     */
    protected function registerMessages()
    {
        $messageTypes = [
            'error' => ErrorMessages::class,
            'info' => InfoMessages::class,
            'success' => SuccessMessages::class,
            'warning' => WarningMessages::class,
        ];
        foreach ($messageTypes as $messageType) {
            $this->app[WidgetsRegistryInterface::class]->registerWidget($messageType);
        }

        $this->app->singleton('sleeping_owl.message', function () use ($messageTypes) {
            return new MessageStack($messageTypes);
        });
    }

    protected function initializeNavigation()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            TableHeaderColumnInterface::class,
            \SleepingOwl\Admin\Display\TableHeaderColumn::class
        );

        $this->app->bind(
            RepositoryInterface::class,
            \SleepingOwl\Admin\Repositories\BaseRepository::class
        );

        $this->app->bind(
            FormButtonsInterface::class,
            \SleepingOwl\Admin\Form\FormButtons::class
        );

        $this->app->bind(
            \KodiComponents\Navigation\Contracts\PageInterface::class,
            \SleepingOwl\Admin\Navigation\Page::class
        );

        $this->app->bind(
            \KodiComponents\Navigation\Contracts\BadgeInterface::class,
            \SleepingOwl\Admin\Navigation\Badge::class
        );

        $this->app->singleton('sleeping_owl.navigation', function () {
            return new Navigation();
        });
    }

    protected function registerWysiwyg()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('sleeping_owl.wysiwyg', function () {
            return new Manager($this->app);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register bootstrap file.
     */
    protected function registerBootstrap()
    {
        $directory = $this->getBootstrapPath();

        if (! is_dir($directory)) {
            return;
        }

        $files = Finder::create()
            ->files()
            ->name('/^.+\.php$/')
            ->notName('routes.php')
            ->notName('*.blade.php')
            ->notName('navigation.php')
            ->in($directory)
            ->sort(function (SplFileInfo $a) {
                return $a->getFilename() != 'bootstrap.php';
            });

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            require_once $file;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register Alias from App.
     */
    protected function registerAliases()
    {
        AliasLoader::getInstance(config('sleeping_owl.aliases', []));
    }

    /**
     * Register Custom Routes From Users.
     */
    protected function registerCustomRoutes()
    {
        if (file_exists($file = $this->getBootstrapPath('routes.php'))) {
            $this->registerRoutes(function (Router $route) use ($file) {
                require $file;
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register Default Admin Routes.
     */
    protected function registerDefaultRoutes()
    {
        $this->registerRoutes(function (Router $router) {
            (new ModelRouter($this->app, $router))->register($this->app['sleeping_owl']->getModels());

            if (file_exists($routesFile = __DIR__.'/../Http/routes.php')) {
                require $routesFile;
            }

            AliasBinder::registerRoutes($router);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register CKEditor Upload and D&D plugins.
     */
    protected function registerSupportRoutes()
    {
        $domain = config('sleeping_owl.domain', false);

        $middlewares = collect($this->getConfig('middleware'));
        $configGroup = collect([
            'prefix' => $this->getConfig('url_prefix'),
            'middleware' => $middlewares,
        ]);

        if ($domain) {
            $configGroup->put('domain', $domain);
        }

        $this->app['router']->group($configGroup->toArray(), function (Router $route) {
            $route->get('ckeditor/upload/image', [
                'as' => 'admin.ckeditor.upload',
                'uses' => 'SleepingOwl\Admin\Http\Controllers\UploadController@ckEditorStore',
            ]);

            $route->post('ckeditor/upload/image', [
                'as' => 'admin.ckeditor.upload',
                'uses' => 'SleepingOwl\Admin\Http\Controllers\UploadController@ckEditorStore',
            ]);
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param \Closure $callback
     */
    protected function registerRoutes(\Closure $callback)
    {
        $domain = config('sleeping_owl.domain', false);
        $configGroup = collect([
            'prefix' => $this->getConfig('url_prefix'),
            'middleware' => $this->getConfig('middleware'),
        ]);

        if ($domain) {
            $configGroup->put('domain', $domain);
        }

        $this->app['router']->group($configGroup->toArray(), function (Router $route) use ($callback) {
            call_user_func($callback, $route);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register navigation file.
     */
    protected function registerNavigationFile()
    {
        if (file_exists($navigation = $this->getBootstrapPath('navigation.php'))) {
            $items = include $navigation;

            if (is_array($items)) {
                $this->app['sleeping_owl.navigation']->setFromArray($items);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing bootstrap cache files and removing composer.lock ?

Comment: Also can you please share `AdminServiceProvider.php` ?

Comment: @Vipertecpro , after I run composer update to add laravelrus/sleepingowl package, I cannot run any artisan command. After I remove laravelrus/sleepingowl package, I run ```php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:cache ```

I'll add the code in question body.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured this `'template' => SleepingOwl\Admin\Templates\TemplateDefault::class,` in sleeping_owl.php https://github.com/LaravelRUS/SleepingOwlAdmin/blob/master/config/sleeping_owl.php ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had to follow the steps:

1. go `/bootstrap/cache` and delete all files, except `.gitignore`
2. run `./composer.phar install` and `php artisan sleepingowl:install`